# C# Best way to add abunch of sounds to a program and pick a random one to play?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a voice line/Sound to play on form show however I only can play two different sounds and Id like to be able to have a list that gets played at random every time the form is shown, Anyone know the best way to go about this? here's the code I have right now:

```
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.UI > 0)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(_2B.Properties.Resources.russian);
            audio.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(_2B.Properties.Resources.freedom);
            audio.Play();
        }
```

I tried adding a var for the random pick but it didnt work, I was assuming I could possibly do the same thing as this:

```
                if (settings.version < newversionparsed) 
            {
                bunifuCircleProgressbar1.Value +=1;
                var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                var stringChars = new char[8];
                var random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
                {
                    stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                }
                var finalString = new String(stringChars);
```

But im not too sure that it's working like I think, Nor do I know if this is possible.

Comment: Don't new `Random` every time. Keep using the same one. You may try 10 `new Random().Next` and a `Random` uses 10 times of `Next`.

Comment: So should I just take out the new? and have it be  `var random = Random();` However if I do that it errors. Im mainly trying to get the random sounds to work for the top bit of code, The bottom bit is for a different part in my project thats working fine but I was seeing if I could use the same concept but for sound.

Comment: Im trying to comprehend but I dont think I am, Are you meaning something like this?

`          if (Properties.Settings.Default.UI > 0)
            {
                new Random().Next();
                SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(_2B.Properties.Resources.russian);
                SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(_2B.Properties.Resources.byebye);
                audio.Play();
            }
`
Also as you can see I actually dont even know how I can store multiple sounds because I want to have different sounds for different values selected I dont know what thats not embedding

Comment: I post an answer as a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of `Random` somewhere, ideally static so you can easily reuse the same instance:

```
static Random random = new Random();
```

Create an array of all the sounds you want available to you:

```
string[] Stream = new Stream[] {
    _2B.Properties.Resources.russian,
    _2B.Properties.Resources.freedom
    // Add as many sounds as you want
};
```

Then when you want to get a sound to play:

```
string sound = sounds[random.Next(sounds.Length)];
SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(sound);
```

Comment: I think this might be the answer im looking for but Where would I place the string? When i  copy it in it errors the properties and if I type it in manually I cant have more than one sound without an error :/ Sorry im a bit of a brainlet hehe

Comment: [Code screenshot](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/519746675133382656/733171383349280768/unknown.png) I placed it here and thought i could place it underneath but idk, Im trying to have a random sound play pretty much right as the form is shown. I got it with the two that i can but i cant add the extra ones in or randomize it. I feel like im being dumb here and its actually really simple but im just lost.

Comment: @Russianfkr Is `_2B.Properties.Resources.russian` a `Stream` instead of a `string`? Try changing the `string[]` array to a `Stream[]`. (e.g. `Stream[] sounds = new Stream[]`). Also you're missing the closing `}` brace in the variable list.

Comment: Ooo switching it worked! Now the last thing is right. Now that its random I still want it to be a more SORTED type of random so im pretty much making a UI voice and its between Male and Female so Id like the audio that plays to be the selected Male Or Female from the first form (Login) as shown here : [LoginForum](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/519746675133382656/733138319591997460/unknown.png) and when that next forum comes up a random sound BUT FROM that value is played. Is that possible?

Comment: @Russianfkr If I understand correctly, just make two arrays of sounds, one male and one female.

Comment: And so far for the first forum I have the idea setup but id just like to add more sounds in there proper area if that makes sense. Ive done it [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/519746675133382656/733176302152056852/unknown.png) but its only one sound at a time.. Ohhh I seeeee I wasnt aware I could put the array inside of the if else

Answer (score 1):

Keep your `Random` so you would get a reasonable result

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1)

> On the .NET Framework, initializing two random number generators in a tight loop or in rapid succession creates two random number generators that can produce identical sequences of random numbers. In most cases, this is not the developer's intent and can lead to performance issues, because instantiating and initializing a random number generator is a relatively expensive process.

> Both to improve performance and to avoid inadvertently creating separate random number generators that generate identical numeric sequences, we recommend that you create one Random object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of creating new Random objects to generate one random number.

So create one and use it multiple times is better.
Note: `Random` is not thread safe, but [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1) has an example for thread safe version.

Following is the example.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    int len = 10;
    int seed = 7;
    string newEverytime = "";
    for( int i =0 ; i < len; i++){
        newEverytime+= new Random().Next( seed ).ToString();
    }
    Console.WriteLine( newEverytime ); // print something fixed
    string get10Next="";
    Random r = new Random();
    for( int i =0 ; i < len; i++){
        get10Next+=r.Next(seed);
    }
    Console.WriteLine( get10Next );  // print random string
}
```

For your program, you need to `new` a `Random` as a class member.

```
class Foo{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    void PlaySound(){
        int val = rnd.Next( 1 ); // use a seed you like
        // implement your play sound
    }
}
```